# Spring Boot 2 - Hibernate and javax.validation annotations

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, bean-validation

I had a Spring Boot 1.x application that I've migrated to Spring Boot 2.1.2.RELEASE. I had some JPA entities annotated with `javax.validation` constraints, as the following:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @NotNull
    private String username;

}
```

This was generating the following ddl for MySQL:

```
create table user (username varchar(255) not null);
```

Now these constraints are ignored and I don't understand why. Do you have any hints?

Comment: Since a Java Bean Validation annotation is nothing to do with the JPA API, and consequently not portable in terms of JPA schema generation then ask yourself why you are relying on such JPA provider specific stuff when JPA provides its own ways of achieving the same

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem 3 days ago and what worked to me was:

1) Stop spring boot
2) Eliminate the database
3) Restart the spring boot to generate it again

I also tried to change the annotation from `@NotNull` to `@Column(nullable=false)`, but it doesn't work.

Let me know if it works for you too!

Comment: In fact I added `@Column(nullable=false)` for every `@NotNull` (note, adding, not substituting, as I was using these annotation for bean validation) and it seems to work but I don't understand why this has been disabled.